# loop to each td and get its text and then replace each td's content with an input box

Tags: javascript, jquery

When clicked on a table's `tr`, I want to loop through each `td` within that clicked `tr` and get it text, then replace each `td`'s content with an input checkbox with a value of each `td`'s text within that clicked table's `tr`.

My html:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-id="1">
            <td>Jason</td>
            <td>USA</td>
            <td>Not specified</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-id="2">
            <td>Micheal</td>
            <td>USA</td>
            <td>Not specified</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-id="3">
            <td>Jason</td>
            <td>Thailand</td>
            <td>222-222</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

my script

```
$("table tr").click(function(){
    $("td", this).each(function(){
        var this_text = $("this").text();
        //I dont know what to do next here
    });
});
```

To sharpen the details, when any of the table's `tr` is clicked, it will loop to each of its childrens (td) and get its text, replace each children's content (td's content) with an input checkbox that has a value of each children's text (td's text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
$("table tr").click(function(){
  $("td:not(:has(input))", this).html(function(i,html){
    return  "<input type='text' value='" + html + "'/>";
  });
});
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ufnvs3yo/)**

Comment: in your demo, when I click into any of the tr, yes it shown an input box yet the value doesnt correspond to its text (td's text content)? any ideas?

Comment: when I click into the input box, its content is replaced by the input codes like "<input type="text" ...>". Any ideas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78764/discussion-between-code-demon-and-milind-anantwar).

Answer (score 0):

You can

```js
$("table").on('click', 'tbody tr:not(.editable)', function() {
  $(this).addClass('editable')
  $("td", this).not(':has(input)').each(function() {
    var $input = $('<input />', {
      value: this.innerHTML.trim()
    });
    $(this).html($input)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-id="1">
      <td>Jason</td>
      <td>USA</td>
      <td>Not specified</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-id="2">
      <td>Micheal</td>
      <td>USA</td>
      <td>Not specified</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-id="3">
      <td>Jason</td>
      <td>Thailand</td>
      <td>222-222</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: There is some weird behavior with your fiddle, if you click inside the text boxes it is appending the texboxes again.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line

```
 $(this).html('<input type="text" value="'+this_text+'"/>');
```

so it will be like  this

```
$("table tr").click(function(){
    $("td", this).each(function(){
        var this_text = $(this).text();
        $(this).html('<input type="text" value="'+this_text+'"/>');
    });
});
```

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/3wfqqpu8/)

By the way you have a error in your code in line

```
var this_text = $("this").text();
```

`$("this")` will be just `$(this)`

---

**Update**
IF you want to preserve the text value also in future  click the you have to do a little more coding, like:

```
    $("table tr").click(function(){
    $("td", this).each(function(){
        var inputFound=$(this).find('input');
        if(inputFound.length == 0)
        {
             var this_text = $(this).text();
            $(this).html('<input type="text" value="'+this_text+'"/>');
        }

    });
});
```

[See this update](https://jsfiddle.net/3wfqqpu8/2/)

Comment: in your demo, when I click into any of the tr, yes it shown an input box yet when I click into the input box, the value of the input is suddenly gone? any ideas?

Comment: yah that's another case. let me fix this.